# Django model u'id' clashes when using OneToOneField

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I have created a model **UserProfile** to relate model **User**.

I got error when doing *python manage.py makemigrations*:

> django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Local field u'id' in class 'UserProfile' clashes with field of similar name from base class 'User'

Here's the code:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='user_of')
    description = models.TextField()

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

Environment: Django 1.8.2, Python 2.7.6, PostgreSQL 9.4.2

Is that a bug? How come does the u'id' of 'UserProfile' clashes with that of 'User'...

I have tried to add a line in the file *settings.py*:

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'user_profile.UserProfile'
```

But that did not work whether it has or not.

How to fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: Try, just for experiment, to remove all migrations and start them from scratch - will the error persist?

Comment: Well problem solved! Why? Gill Bates, just wonderful!   I just remove all the migration files and recreate the database. Thank you!

Comment: This solution comes from that ticket: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21890 But it's about inheritance. I suppose, that you had used inheritance in the past versions and maybe that causes the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I understand now. :) Wish you a nice day!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you probably have is an old migration that used to inherit from the model in question

To test this out clone your project and delete all the migrations and `makemigrations` on a fresh new database

If it works, then track down the offending migration from your current project and don't forget to remove the entry from `django_migrations` table as well